# VBA to copy and paste column based on the text in the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to accomplish the below task, please see the image for reference.

As you can see in columns C, D, and E, there is text such as `X55.656` and `Y922.495` respectively and so on. Now the problem I am facing is that the text with "X" should be placed in column X, and the text starting with "Y" should be placed in the Y column. This has to be done to all the rows containing `X` and `Y`. Can you write a VBA code for me from scratch to help solve my problem?

[image]

The Output should as shown in the below figure,

[image]

Comment: Please share what you have tried with your code

Comment: what do you do if you have `X` in two columns?

Comment: "Can you write a VBA code for me from scratch to help solve my problem?" are you kidding ??? This is not a code writing service! You severly misunderstood how StackOverflow works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to state how you want to handle X or Y occuring in more than one source column in the same row.

If you don't mind overwriting when X or Y occurs multiple times in a row you can use the following as a starting point:

```
Dim wb as workbook
Dim ws as worksheet
Dim LastRow as long
Dim rng as Range
Dim row as Range
Dim cell as Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheetname") 'change as appropriate

'Assuming column C, D  and E have end items in the same row (otherwise consider finding lastrow using current region. 
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, "C"), ws.Cells(LastRow, "E"))

For Each row in rng.Rows
    For Each cell in row.cells
        If Lcase(Left(cell.Value,1)) = "x" Then
            If Mid(cell.Address, 2, 1) = "C" Then
                cell.Offset(0, 21) = cell.Value
            Elseif Mid(cell.Address, 2, 1) = "D" Then
                cell.Offset(0, 20) = cell.Value
            Else: cell.Offset(0, 19) = cell.Value
            End If
            cell.clearcontents
        End If
        If Lcase(Left(cell.Value,1)) = "y" Then
            If Mid(cell.Address, 2, 1) = "C" Then
                cell.Offset(0, 22) = cell.Value
            Elseif Mid(cell.Address, 2, 1) = "D" Then
                cell.Offset(0, 21) = cell.Value
            Else: cell.Offset(0, 20) = cell.Value
            End If
            cell.clearcontents
        End If
    Next Cell
Next row
End Sub
```

Different ways of finding LastRow [Finding LastRow](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm)

Comment: Hi , thanks for the solution. As you can see  in C column x is in row 1 and 2 but in column D x is in 3 rd row. so after arranging the value in x column should be as X55.656 , X70.711 , X113.137 one below the other respectively. so if the value of X is in column c:1 it wont be there in any other column:1 it might be in column D:2. the final output should be all the x in one column and all the y in other column.

Comment: I have added the an image which shows how the output should be. Kindly refer the image.

Comment: and seems like one closing braces is missing in the following statement.               Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, "C"), ws.Range(ws.Cells(LastRow, "E"))

Comment: "Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, "C"), ws.Range(ws.Cells(LastRow, "E"))" in this statement when the program is executed there is an error stating Range_of_object_failed and the rng variable contains "nothing"

Comment: I have updated code. You will need to write the code to determine how to handle overwrites. This is intended to give you a framework.

Comment: okay no problem...Thank you so much !!

Comment: Thank you so much Qharr. that really worked for me !!. thank u again ...